# Non-Lie Subgroups of GLn(R)

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups

Is there any subgroups of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ which are not Lie groups. Some trivial examples I know like $\mathbb{Q}^*\subset \mathbb{R}^*$ which are $0$-dimensional cases. I am looking for some examples where the subgroup has higher dimension. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrices of form$\left(\begin{smallmatrix}x&0\\0&q\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, with $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ and $q\in\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$ form a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ which is not a Lie subgroup.

On the other hand, there's a theorem due to Élie Cartan which states that every closed subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is again a Lie group.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second part is well known. But can you please describe why this is not a Lie group?

Comment: @SKH Because it's not even a submanifold. Or you can use the fact that Cartan's theorem is actually an equivalence: a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a Lie group if and only if it is closed.

Comment: The converse is really amazing, thank you for this information ! Can I see e precise reference for the converse? Thank you again!

Comment: See, for instance, J. M. Lee's *Introduction to smooth manifolds* (proposition 8.30).

Comment: Proposition  8.30 seems to have no such information.

Comment: But Theorem 7.21.  says the following: "Suppose G is a Lie group and H < G is a Lie subgroup. Then H
is closed in G if and only if it is embedded.

Comment: @SKH I am sorry. I meant corollary 15.30.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: It's not true that a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb R)$ is a Lie group if and only if it's closed (and my book doesn't claim that). For example, there's an immersed 1-dimensional Lie subgroup of $GL_4(\mathbb R)$ whose closure is a torus. It's given by an injective immersion $F\colon \mathbb R\to GL_4(\mathbb R)$ defined as follows: $F(t)$ rotates the first two coordinates through an angle $t$, and the second two coordinates through an angle $at$, where $a$ is some irrational number.

Comment: @JackLee You are right, of course. I forgot that I should have written **embedded** Lie group.